# SDL2 Getting weird colors

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm creating a simple tile-based game using SDL2. I've drawn my tiles on two layers. The problem is the second layer which as you can see with the image below for some reason tiles with something already drawn underneath have a reddish tint. The corner and side tiles for the grass should be exactly the same color, for example.

Here's an image of my problem:

[image: an image of my problem]

Here's my tilesheet:

[image: tilesheet]

And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 640;
//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* window = NULL;
//The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;
//Holds built base layer of tilemap.
SDL_Surface* baseLayer = NULL;
//Map Data array
char mapLayerOne[20][20] = {
{4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,6,8,8,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,6,8,8,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,6,6,8,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,6,6,8,8,8,8,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,8,6,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,6,6,14,6,6,8,8,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4   },
{4,4,4,6,14,16,14,6,6,8,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4 },
{4,4,4,14,16,16,16,12,8,8,8,8,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4   },
{4,4,4,6,16,16,16,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,6,4,4,4,4,4 },
{4,4,4,6,6,16,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,8,6,4,4,4,4,4   },
{4,4,13,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,8,6,4,4,4,4,4   },
{4,4,4,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,4,4,4,4   },
{4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4    },
{4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4    }
};
char mapLayerTwo[20][20] = {
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,0,11,18,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,7,19,0,12,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,0,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,5,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,17,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,12,10,11,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,12,18,19,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,12,2,3,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,8,0,0,3,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,8,0,0,7,0,0,0 }
};
bool init();
void DrawTiles(SDL_Surface *image, char mapLayer);

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
  //Main loop flag
  bool quit = false;
  //Event handler
  SDL_Event e;

  if(init())
  {
    //Load images
    SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load("Images/TileSheet_01.png");
    if (!image)
    std::cout << "Failed to load TileSheet_01.png!" << std::endl;
    //Create BaseLayers of map
    DrawTiles(image, 1);
    DrawTiles(image, 2);

    //While application is running
    while (!quit)
    {
        //Handle events on queue
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
        {
            //User requests quit
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                quit = true;
        }
        //Get window surface
        screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window); 

        //Blit base layer of map to screenSurface
        SDL_BlitSurface(baseLayer, NULL, screenSurface, NULL);
        //Update the surface
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        //Delay in milliseconds to improve performance
        SDL_Delay(1);
    }
  }
  //Destroy window
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  //Quit SDL subsystems
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}

void DrawTiles(SDL_Surface *image, char mapLayer)
{
  SDL_Rect baseTile[20];
  int tileX = 0;
  int tileY = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
  {
    baseTile[i].h = 32;
    baseTile[i].w = 32;
    baseTile[i].x = tileX;
    baseTile[i].y = tileY;
    tileX += 32;
    if (tileX == 128) { tileY += 32; tileX = 0; }
  }
  //Fill the surface
  SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 150, 50, 50));
  SDL_Rect tileLoc;
  tileLoc.x = 0;
  tileLoc.y = 0;
  // Draw tiles
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
     {
        if (mapLayer == 1 && mapLayerOne[i][j] != 0)
            SDL_BlitSurface(image, &baseTile[mapLayerOne[i][j]], baseLayer, &tileLoc);
        else if (mapLayer == 2 && mapLayerTwo[i][j] != 0)
            SDL_BlitSurface(image, &baseTile[mapLayerTwo[i][j]], baseLayer, &tileLoc);
        tileLoc.x += 32;
        if (tileLoc.x == 640)
        {
            tileLoc.x = 0;
            tileLoc.y += 32;
        }
    }
  }
}

bool init()
{
  //Initialization flag
  bool success = true;

  //Initialize SDL
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
  {
    std::cout << "SDL could not initialize!" << std::endl;
    success = false;
  }
  else
  {
    //Create window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("My SDL TileMap", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Window could not be created!" << std::endl;
        success = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        //Initialize PNG loading
        int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
        if (!(IMG_Init(imgFlags) & imgFlags))
        {
            //std::cout << "SDL_image could not initialize!" << std::endl;
            printf("SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
            //Surface to hold baselayer of map.
            baseLayer = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
SDL_Delay(300);
return success;
}
```

What's causing this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post some code (as a text into the question)

Comment: There could be any number of reasons, including blending, colour modifiers or just data being loaded differently. I'm not even sure what we're supposed to see on the screenshot. Impossible to answer in current state, sorry.

Comment: Have I done something horrible by asking a question here? Why am I getting more negative rep than every other question on this site ever as far as I can tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
baseLayer = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
                                                                  ^^ ...but you're using 32bpp PNGs
```

Use a 32-bit surface instead of 16 and populate the masks:

```
    // https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface#Code_Examples
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
    const Uint32 rmask = 0xff000000;
    const Uint32 gmask = 0x00ff0000;
    const Uint32 bmask = 0x0000ff00;
    const Uint32 amask = 0x000000ff;
#else
    const Uint32 rmask = 0x000000ff;
    const Uint32 gmask = 0x0000ff00;
    const Uint32 bmask = 0x00ff0000;
    const Uint32 amask = 0xff000000;
#endif
    baseLayer = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 32, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask );
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was my problem! I made the mistake of thinking the problem was more complicated.